# more specific LIKE search with defined variables

Tags: php, mysql

i have a script that searches my database for hashtags, i need to search s.data for specific things $tag is defined and would be the hashtag ex. #peter when i search fo rhashtag #peter i get the results of #peters #peterson #peterpeter. how do i cut the string off at the end so it only searches for results matching exactly #peter

i have tried

```
 REGEXP '[[:<:]]#$tag[[:>:]]'
```

but that didnt return any result.
below is my original code

```
 $sql = "SELECT s.*, u.avatar
        FROM status AS s
        LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.username = s.author
        WHERE s.author IN ('$friendsCSV') AND (s.data LIKE '%#$tag%') AND (s.type='a' OR s.type='c' OR s.type='d')
        ORDER BY s.postdate DESC LIMIT 20";
```

Comment: That isn't a valid regexp. Try something like `\\b#$tag\\b`.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn MySQL doesn't use `\b`.

Comment: @Barmar bah, thanks. I see that now.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
 AND s.data REGEXP '#$tag[[:>:]]'
```

Don't use `[[:<:]]` before `#`, because this only matches before the start of a word, and `#` is not a word character.

Also,

```
(s.type='a' OR s.type='c' OR s.type='d')
```

is better written as:

```
s.type IN ('a', 'c', 'd')
```

If `$friendsCSV` is a comma-separated list, you should use `FIND_IN_SET` to search it:

```
FIND_IN_SET(s.author, '$friendsCSV')
```

`IN` expects each value to search for to be a separate string in the `()` list, not a single string with commas.

Comment: should i remove the LIKE also? or will it be LIKE REGEXP

Comment: `LIKE` and `REGEXP` are two different operators. `LIKE` is for matching wildcard patterns, `REGEXP` is for matching a regular expression.

Comment: thank you. the hashtag search function isnt returning any result yet

Comment: See the last part about `$friendsCSV`.

Comment: `WHERE` `FIND_IN_SET` (s.author, '$friendsCSV') ?

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT s.*, u.avatar
  FROM status AS s
  LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.username = s.author
  WHERE FIND_IN_SET (s.author, '$friendsCSV') AND s.data REGEXP '#$tag[[:>:]]' AND s.type IN ('a', 'c', 'd')
  ORDER BY s.postdate DESC LIMIT 20";` no results yet

Comment: Can you make a sqlfiddle with sample data?

Comment: so i think my friendsCSV is the problem, i think it may be inserting some spaces or something in the string

Comment: `$friendsCSV = join("','", $all_friends);`

Comment: echos this = laila','adam','alex','meegs','mario','country','dad','mm','alexandra so maybe this symbol ' is  causing the error?

Comment: Take out the quotes, it should be `$friendsCSV = implode(",", $all_friends);`

Answer (score 0):

If the data in `data` is something like `'#tag1#tag2#tag7#tag4'` then this condition should work

`(data LIKE '%#$tag#%' OR data LIKE '%#$tag')`

I'd warn about losing indexing advantages with the `OR`, but the leading wildcard already makes that a moot point.

Comment: it gives no results when modified like that (s.data LIKE '%#$tag#%' OR s.data LIKE '%#$tag')

Comment: This will only work if the hashtag is at the end of `data` or is followed immediately by another hashtag.

Comment: @peter what is the content of the `$tag` variable.

Comment: @Barmar assuming the data is formatted as I prefaced with, it covers all possible positions within the data string. _(If it is the only tag, it is at the end; and if it is not the last one, it must be followed by another.)_

Comment: TAG variable is defined from the url and it would be the single hashtag text following the # sign. so  #hashone would  be $tag= hashone

Comment: @peter After looking at the fiddle you provided in the other answer, it looks like the format of `data` was different than I prefaced; from the information you provided there it is not clear whether you are trying to get `things with hash 'hash'` or `things with hashes starting with 'hash'`. If the former, and you can count on tagged words/phrases being followed by a space (unless they are the last word/phrase) you should just be able to use something very similar to what I stated above; just change `'%#$tag#%'` to `'%#$tag %'`. _If the latter, your original query should've been acceptable._

Comment: so far the answer that works the best, how do i get it to capture hashtags that have no 'space' at the end ?

Comment: @peter What I've provided should cover tags that have spaces after them, and tags at the very end. What else would they have? I mean, I can understand wanting search on `#abc` to not return data with `#abcd`, but without knowing what characters you permit in a tag, it is a guessing game. _(ex: Is `#ac/dc` a valid tag, or should it be considered the `#ac` followed the the text `/dc`?)_  ..and the more disallowed characters there are the more likely the best answer is going to involve REGEXP.